# Executing a binary at works but binary is not actually at path

Tags: directory, ls, path, binary

If I run `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy testing.plist` it works.
But if I `cd /usr/libexec` and run `ls -al` I can't see `PlistBuddy` listed in that directory.

Why is that?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`? Remember ls will sort the upper case names first, then display a sorted list of lowercase names.

Comment: That was it @datUser the sorting of the upper case first. I was looking amoughst the lower case list. Doh! Thanks.

Comment: @datUser: Looks like you pointed out the issue with your first comment. Please do format your comment and post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @robdashnash : Accept the posted answer if it resolves. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ls -al /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` correctly shows the `PlistBuddy` binary, then the issue is probably that a quick visual scan of the output of `ls` was read incorrectly.

Depending on the system and/or the locale, `ls` may sort the upper case names first, then display a sorted list of lowercase names.